# Application of Stoke's Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Edit:
I think I misunderstood the problem. Upon reading my textbook again, I think what they mean by

> $F(x,y,z)=<yz,2xz,e^{xy}>$ ; C is the circle $x^2+y^2=16, z=5$

is just literally a circle of radius 4 at z=5. So the region S does not have to be a cylinder? Then what is the relation between S and C?

Edit #2:
Yes, the region does not need to be a cylinder! It can be anything that yields the corresponding boundary region c. So to make life easier for ourselves, take the region S to be that of c!!!

I think I answered my own question! Sometimes all it takes is time and more time to reread the textbook!

Cheers!

---

I am attempting the following question, and I am not getting nice results.

> Use Stoke's theorem to evaluate $\int_cFdr$. In each case C is oriented counterclockwise as viewed from above:
>   $F(x,y,z)=<yz,2xz,e^{xy}>$ ; C is the circle $x^2+y^2=16, z=5$

So the first thing is to sketch the boundary of intersection C that corresponds to a region S which should be a right circular cone of radius 4 and height 5.

I parameterized the surface using: $$r(\theta,z)=<4cos\theta,4sin\theta,z>,\{ (\theta,z)\in R | 0 \leq z \leq 5  \, \& \, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi \}$$
Calculating the normal vector:
$$r_\theta=<-4sin(\theta),4cos(\theta),0>$$ 
$$r_z =<0,0,1> $$ 
$$r_\theta \times r_z= <4cos(\theta),4sin(\theta),0>$$

(Here, the solution manual choose the normal vector as $n=<0,0,1>$ why?? I really really don't get this part )

Moreover I calculated $$curlF= \nabla \times F = <xe^{xy}-2x, ye^{xy}-y, 2z-z>$$

Then by Stokes's theorem,

$$\int_cFdr= \iint_S curl F \cdot n dS$$
$$ = \int_0^5 \int_0^{2\pi} <xe^{xy}-2x, ye^{xy}-y, 2z-z> \cdot <4cos(\theta),4sin(\theta),0> d\theta dz$$

I get stuck here, because first of all I make an assumption that is make the substitutions: $x=4cos\theta$ and $y=4sin\theta$ into the above integral (I don't have to worry about z variable because the dot product gets rid of it). Is this correct?

Finally, after the substitution, the integral is still not easy to evaluate. The correct solution to the problem is: $80\pi$

Any help is really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I believe you must close the surface, i.e, consider the area at the bottom of the cilinder you discribed, that normal vector described is perpendicular to both: the top and bottom faces